# NetSuite RESTlet Error code: INVALID_RETURN_DATA_FORMAT

Tags: rest, netsuite

I'm attempting to call a saved search through the RESTlet API and I have my RESTlet deployed, but when attempting to run it, I'm getting the following error:

> error code: INVALID_RETURN_DATA_FORMAT
>
> error message:Invalid data format. You should return TEXT.

Looking through my script, I can't identify where the error is. Below is the script that I'm attempting to run

```
function GetSearchResult(){
    //array container for search results
    var output = new Array();
    
    //get search results
    var results = nlapiSearchRecord('transaction','customsearchid',null,null);
    var columns = results[0].getAllColumns();
    
    //loop through the search results
    for(var i in results){
        //create placeholder object place holder
        var obj = new searchRow(
          //set the values of the object with the values of the appropriate columns
          results[i].getValue(columns[0]),
          results[i].getValue(columns[1]),
          results[i].getValue(columns[2]),
          results[i].getValue(columns[3]),
          results[i].getValue(columns[4]),
          results[i].getValue(columns[5]),
          results[i].getValue(columns[6]),
          results[i].getValue(columns[7]),
          results[i].getValue(columns[8]),
          results[i].getValue(columns[9]),
          results[i].getValue(columns[10]),
          results[i].getValue(columns[11]),
          results[i].getValue(columns[12])
          );
        
        //add the object to the array of results
        output.push(obj);
    }
    
    //return the array of search objects
    return output;
}

//Object to serve a place holder for each search row
function searchRow(internalid,lineid,subsidiaryid,locationid,departmentid,accountid,date,name,memo,amount,uniqueid,product,period){
    this.internalid = internalid;
    this.lineid = lineid;
    this.subsidiaryid = subsidiaryid;
    this.locationid = locationid;
    this.departmentid = departmentid;
    this.accountid = accountid;
    this.date = date;
    this.name = name;
    this.memo = memo;
    this.amount = amount;
    this.uniqueid = uniqueid;
    this.product = product;
    this.period = period;

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you are sending a `Content-Type` header of `application/json` with your request. I believe you'll also need to `return JSON.stringify(output);` rather than just `return output;`

You also do not want to use JavaScript's `for..in` with Arrays; it is [only meant for Object iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). Instead you should use a standard `for` loop.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is just that you need the content-type application/json in the request.

for..in works fine with real arrays. Netsuite's search results don't always behave as real arrays so I'll often do

```
var x = (nlapiSearchRecord(...) || []);

x.forEach(function(r){

});
```

As far as JSON goes I just return the object. I've never had the error you are experiencing -- If I send a GET request without a Content-Type header I get an error -- it's possible your client program is setting content type of text/plain and that's why NS expects text output.

Just a bit of follow-up:
If you send the header, even on a GET request, Netsuite will interpret your query string, if you have one, as an object of key-value pairs and will pass that to your function AND will transmit your returned object as JSON so no need to call JSON.stringify yourself.

If you don't set the header then you'd have to call JSON.parse on the passed in data and JSON.stringify on the returned data if you want your client programs to receive JSON. This is a bit odd since the standard way would be for Netsuite to look at the Accept: header and formulate the data appropriately. Netsuite does actually spell this out (sort of) in their help:https://system.na1.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4619215993.html